# best practice posting complex object to api

Tags: rest, api-design

i am trying to figure out what is the best practice on doing POST calls when creating new complex objects.

example assume this is the complex object i wish to send:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "mainEmployer": {"name": "Imaginary LLC", "website": "www.imaginary.com"}
}
```

essentially the above is 2 models in one.

person model:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

employment model:

```
{
    "personId": "whatever John Doe's unique ID in system is",
    "name": "Imaginary LLC",
    "website": "www.imaginary.com"
}
```

Is it better practice to send one at a time (multiple post calls), constructed in such way that employment model wait for successful creation of person model, and then sending it (with the updated ID), or should i bundle it all up into a single complex object as per first example and send it to a single api that will then disseminate it across multiple microservices.
Assume that person model and employment model sit within separate microservice.

So far I've seen cases for both single api call and multi api calls for individual objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better practice to send one at a time (multiple post calls), constructed in such way that employment model wait for successful creation of person model, and then sending it (with the updated ID), or should i bundle it all up into a single complex object as per first example and send it to a single api that will then disseminate it across multiple microservices.

Bundle it up, although it shouldn't look like you are bundling anything up, it should just look like a single resource.

That would make most sense from the point of view of your users.

Remember you are building a REST API. The only thing your API users should care about are the Resources exposed by that API. If this object

```
{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "mainEmployer": {"name": "Imaginary LLC", "website": "www.imaginary.com"}
}
```

represent a Resource that a user of the API wants to GET or PUT to, then treat it as a single resource.

Something your users most certainly do not care about and do not want to care about is anything that happens behind your API to store or save this information. If your system breaks this Resource up into 1, 5, 10, 100 individual data structures to process it with a dozen microservices or across multiple databases, your users don't care.

So I wouldn't even think of this is a 'bundling' anything up. You have 3 resources, a ***Person*** resource, an ***Employment*** resource and what ever you want to call a ***Person with Employment information included*** resource

Even if behind the scenes you only actually store 2 objects in a database, a row in the `persons` table and a row in the `employment` table, with a link between the two, your users don't care. This is an implementation detail of your server.

Have as many Resources as makes sense to your users, and don't expose implementation details of your server to your users.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to implement your use-cases as simply/easy as possible, that means preferably with one call.

That also means that single use-cases shouldn't be distributed at all, unless specifically in reaction to requirements, because that obviously adds a lot of complexity.

So, it should be one call, but this call should go to a service that can actually deal with this call itself, and not delegate to multiple other services. Again, if no other requirements force it that way.

Also, if there are 2 calls, I would expect to be led by hypertext through the steps, not by hardcoded choreography.

Comment: So in case of a distributed micro service where one entity sits in one service while another sits in another, should you still be using single call and have the data distributed to second microservice through event or internal api call?

Comment: @Aeseir If both services are under your control, then that is already a sub-optimal design, because it is not capable of handling your use-case properly. *But*, if there are 2 services, can not be changed, then I would expect hypertext to be the glue between them. Forms, links, etc. If that also isn't available, then it starts to not matter that much. So yeah, hardcode two calls into the client, that is still simpler then having a third service that effectively does nothing.

Comment: thanks so for my clarity if we cannot bring the disparate services together and run a single call, then make multiple calls to the specific services

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

Both being stored in different data sources is irrelevant for the client.  So, think about how you want the client to interact with the API.

If `person` and `employee` are two elements that change at the same time (or often) due to the same reason or if they must be synchronized all the time, one transfer object bundling both elements is ok.

If you want to limit or cut down the number of calls to the API, as for dealing with env constrains or as for ease the client's workflow, one transfer object bundling both elements is fine.

Same if you are implementing a mere service for bulk loads.

Eventual consistency is another factor to take into account that is best handled from the server-side than from the client-side. So it's preferable to allow clients to send all the data and let the server to do the heavy lifting and deal with the burden of the eventual consistency.

On the other hand, if eventual consistency is not a problem and if your system allows creating one and, eventually, create the other, two calls to the API should be fine too.

There are several factors to take into account and there are questions we can not answer for you.

I would dare to say, both approaches are fine. Depending on the context, one solution would be more "adequate" than the other, but that's circumstantial (requirements change) and as usual a matter of tradeoffs (pros should compensate the cons, somehow).